# Mongodb query getting slow even after indexing

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection let's say Fruits in db. which has following fields

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId(...),
 "item": "Banana",
 "category": ["food", "produce", "grocery"],
 "location": "4th Street Store",
 "stock": 4,
 "type": "cases"
}
```

There is an index by default on _id, and i added another index which is,

```
{
 "item": "1",
 "category": "1",
 "stock": "1",
 "type": "1"
}
```

this collection has data of thousands , and my query response is slow. My query is.

> After the index which I mentioned above, Do I need to add all these
> checks in my query or I can use any on the keys added in the index ?

Like, currently my queries are like

```
fruits.find({item: 'new'});
fruits.find({item: 'new', category: 'history'});
fruits.find({stock: '5', category: 'drama'});
fruits.find({type: 'new'});
```

> Is my index which has all these keys is enough for this or I need to
> created different indexes for all these combination of keys which I
> mentioned above?

Sometimes I am using query and sometimes I am using aggregation on some other collections and lookup for this fruits collections and then doing search etc..

Comment: Can you please show the result of the explain query ?

Comment: good explanation in [mongodb compound index docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes), just follow the instruction as per docs.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
 "item": "1",
 "category": "1",
 "stock": "1",
 "type": "1"
}
```

This index will partially work for the following.

```
fruits.find({item: 'new'}); **Will work (Partially)**
fruits.find({item: 'new', category: 'history'}); **Will work (Partially)**
fruits.find({stock: '5', category: 'drama'}); **Won't work**
fruits.find({type: 'new'}); **Won't work**
```

Partially => The index is basically an addition in a B-Tree data structure in MongoDB which maps a document in the system. The index prefix on item allows the index to work for first and second query you mentioned but it would be a collection scan for third and last one.

Read about [prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#std-label-compound-index-prefix) here.

You need to properly understand indexes in the long run, for queries specifically you can seek help but the knowledge gap will become a problem. [This](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) brief read will be really useful.

Edit

Aggregation => Depends on part of the query, mostly only for match you can use index thereafter everything else happens in memory(Check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#aggregation-pipeline-optimization) for more details). For lookup you fetch the data using index on other collection if you have the index on it (again the match part) but after fetching that data whatever you do extra on it would be done in memory. Logically, mostly the fetching of data will be where indexes will be used anyway, for sorting part read the document linked above.

Comment: Ok i Got it, this logic will be same if we are running aggregation on collection with lookup etc ?

Comment: Aggregation => Depends on part of the query, mostly only for match you can use index thereafter everything else happens in memory. For lookup you fetch the data using index on other collection if you have the index on it (again the match part.)

Comment: @MuhammadAadilBanaras Updated the answer, consider accepting this as an answer.